# какую функцию использовать для расшифровки сообщения через словарь?

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, char> DecryptingDict = new Dictionary<string, char>()
    {
        { "Its A", 'A' }, 
        { "Its B", 'B' }, 
    };

        Console.Write("Enter any text: ");
        var text = Console.ReadLine();
        var decrypted_text = Decrypted(text, DecryptingDict);
}

public static string Decrypted(string sourse, Dictionary<string, char> DecryptingDict)
{
    var decrypt_text = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var elem in sourse)
    {
        if (DecryptingDict.ContainsKey(elem))
        {
            decrypt_text.Append(DecryptingDict[elem]);
        }

        else
        {
            decrypt_text.Append(elem);
        }
    }

    return decrypt_text.Tostring();
}
```

На эту функцию, а конкретно на часть с циклом foreach и DecryptingDict.ContainsKey(elem)
decrypt_text.Append(DecryptingDict[elem],
ругается Visual Studio! говорит, что нельзя преобразовать char в string!
какую тогда мне использовать функцию для расшифровки сообщения?

Comment: Интересно, а подходит ли этот вопрос под категорию "Опечатка"...

Answer (score 2):

`char` это ключ:

```
Dictionary<char, string> DecryptingDict = new Dictionary<char, string>()
{
    { 'A', "It's A" }, 
    { 'B', "It's B" }
};
```